# How to stop playing sound from ActionBar? (soundboard)

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I am creating a soundboard app, and I want to add a button which will stop the playing sound when touching it, to action bar. I searched for the solution but found examples using soundpool, and I created all sounds with MediaPlayer. Please help me?

My project is likes this:

```
MediaPlayer mysound1 ;
MediaPlayer mysound2;
MediaPlayer mysound3 ;
...

    mysound1= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jah_dogdugunkoy) ;
    mysound2=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jah_vidanjor) ;
    mysound3=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jah_borazan) ;
```

and this is for playing audio when I click the button (I use onClick in button)

```
public void mybuttonn1 (View view) {

  mybuton1.start();

}
```

the button's job is only to stop the audio. It will not start it again. I created different button for that.

Comment: Simply call `mysound1.stop(); mysound1.release();` in your Button's `onClick` callback.

Comment: i created this in menu and it will stop sound when clicked, will i add onClick in this? english is not my main language so please explain a little bit clearer :)                                                                                                                                      <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sound"
        android:icon="@drawable/volume_off_white"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always" />

Comment: sort of... If you are creating a menu then you can get the equivalent `onClick()` callback as `onOptionsItemSelected()` there you can stop the mediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

```
  mubutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                        mysound1.pause(); //or stop()
                mybutton2.setEnabled(false);
});
```

Comment: sorry but i cant understand, where i will ride it? i am new to this work :(

Comment: You want to create a second button "mybutton2"

Comment: no, i have got a button for each sound.And on buttons the soundss names are writen.İ want a button which will be on actionbar.For example i will select a sound, and i dislike it and i dont want to wait for sound finishing.So i will tap to mute button on acitonbar and sound will stop.İt will fonly close the song, it wont start it again.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm .... I think this link is about what you want